# Trouble Enabling SSL on Fuseki Server

Tags: jena, fuseki

I'm hoping some of you may be able to help me with setting up SSL on my fuseki server. I've been battling with it for a few days now and am running out of possible solutions!

**OS:** RHEL 8.5 (Ootpa)
**Fuseki:** Version 4.2.0
Currently running as system service with:

> *ExecStart=/home/fuseki/apache-jena-fuseki-4.2.0/fuseki-server -v -tdb2 -update -config=/home/fuseki/fuseki_data/config.ttl*

This is the manual I've been working with- https://jena.apache.org/documentation/fuseki2/fuseki-data-access-control.html

The following are the provided arguments to add in the startup sequence of fuseki-server.

> –https=SETUP        [Name of file for certificate details.]
> & –httpsPort=PORT     [The port for https. Default: 3043]
>
> The --https argument names a file in JSON which includes the name of
> the certificate file and password for the certificate.

The issue is that no matter how I phrase the arguments the process returns **"fuseki-server[9469]: Unknown argument: https"** in the journalctl logs.

I have tried -https=dir, --https=dir, & -httpsConf=dir (where dir is the directory to my cert_details.json file).

Based on the docs https should have native support but when I check *fuseki-server -help* there is no mention of an https argument. I have created a .jks from my cert, have set the correct file permissions, and have allowed 3043.

I have also located the block of code in fuseki that resolves the keystore and passwd from the .json file (which led me to try using -httpsConf=)

> private void setHttpsCert(String filename) {
> try {
> JsonObject **httpsConf = JSON.read(filename)**;
> Path path = Path.of(filename).toAbsolutePath();
> String keystore = **httpsConf.get("keystore").getAsString().value()**;
> **// Resolve relative to the https setup file.**
> this.httpsKeystore = path.getParent().resolve(keystore).toString();
> this.httpsKeystorePasswd = httpsConf.get("passwd").getAsString().value();

Not sure what I'm missing here. For what it's worth I'm a chemist and I definitely don't know java all that well so it very well could be me being stupid. Any suggestions/knowledge would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

there are two ways to get HTTPS+Fuseki:

The document referred to is for the jar file here: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/jena/jena-fuseki-server/4.2.0/jena-fuseki-server-4.2.0.jar, not the jar in the apache-jena-fuseki download. (BTW It does not have the UI.)

The one in the apache-jena-fuseki can be use HTTPS by using a Jetty configuration using `--jetty=jetty.xml` (https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-xml-config.html) -- example: https://github.com/apache/jena/blob/main/jena-fuseki2/examples/fuseki-jetty-https.xml (which will need modifying).